# How to skip row by condition in mysql trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

How to skip one row in cursor loop?

I mentioned as **CONTINUE**; in the above snippet. I want to skip if name='siva'.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `vdata_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `vdata`
BEGIN

declare v_name varchar(100);
declare v_address varchar(100);
declare v_city varchar(50);
declare v_IdentityNO varchar(20)
declare v_clientNo int


declare cur1 cursor for 
        select name,Address,City,IdentityNO,clientNo
        from temptable;
declare continue handler for not found set done=1;

    set done = 0;
    open cur1;
    igmLoop: loop
        fetch cur1 into v_name,v_Address,v_City,v_IdentityNO,v_clientNo;
        if done = 1 then leave igmLoop; end if;
        if v_name = 'siva' then **CONTINUE**;
        insert into audit(name, data) values(v_name, now())
    end loop igmLoop;
    close cur1;
END
```

Answer (score 2):

It is maybe too late but still answering for others.
There is a statement called Iterate which can be used to skip the remaining code.
Here is an example.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
Block1 : BEGIN 
    declare x int default null;
    declare l_a_check int default null;
    declare a cursor for SELECT 1 as ID union (select 2) union (select 3);
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET l_a_check = 1;
        open a;
    loop_a: loop
        fetch a into x;
        if l_a_check = 1 then
                close a;
                leave loop_a;
        end if;
        
        if x = 2 then
            ITERATE loop_a;
        end if;
        
        SELECT x;
    END LOOP loop_a;
    

END Block1;
//
DELIMITER ;
call test();
```

Answer (score 1):

From what the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html) says, it is not possible to skip rows when using a cursor:

> MySQL supports cursors inside stored programs. The syntax is as in embedded SQL. Cursors have these properties:
>
> Asensitive: The server may or may not make a copy of its result table
> Read only: Not updatable
> **Nonscrollable: Can be traversed only in one direction and cannot skip rows**

However, if you look closely at your trigger you will see that there is another way to proceed here.  I think you can just rephrase your logic to only perform that `INSERT` if the `v_name` is *not* `'siva'`:

```
if v_name <> 'siva' then
    insert into audit(name, data) values(v_name, now())
end if;
-- if the name is 'siva' then just flow to the next row fetched from the cursor
```

Even if your actual code be much larger than this, you can *always* phrase an `IF` statement such that it only executes a portion of all of a cursor iteration if some condition be true.

Comment: I just give example to my question. If i change the logic then i have to maintain very big block of code inside that IF block.

Comment: @KumarSiva I don't think such a construct exists in MySQL, but even if it did, you wouldn't need to use it.  You can always construct an `IF` statement to skip over code in the cursor which should not execute for a given fetch.

Comment: Are you saying no CONTINUE in mysql?

Comment: I couldn't find it anywhere.  Maybe someone else will answer.